# VSTS Build - Coded UI Tests Could not be found during Build's Test Execution

Tags: dll, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, coded-ui-tests, azure-pipelines

I have a Coded UI test program that runs without any error on local Visual Studio (2017). Only one test method is in the program. One feature it has is saving file in Azure Storage container. During build's Test Runs process, Build message says it cannot find any tests. Hoping for any feedback to see if I am making any error in build definition.

The build message says:

> No test is available in D:\a\3\s\FullSite1\bin\Debug\FullSite1.dll D:\a\3\s\FullSite1\bin\Debug\Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core.dll D:\a\3\s\FullSite1\bin\Debug\Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll D:\a\3\s\FullSite1\bin\Debug\Microsoft.Data.OData.dll D:\a\3\s\FullSite1\bin\Debug\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll D:\a\3\s\FullSite1\bin\Debug\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll D:\a\3\s\FullSite1\bin\Debug\Newtonsoft.Json.dll D:\a\3\s\packages\Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core.1.0.0\lib\net40\Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core.dll D:\a\3\s\packages\Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core.1.0.0\lib\portable-net45+wp8+wpa81+win\Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core.dll D:\a\3\s\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2\lib\net20\Newtonsoft.Json.dll D:\a\3\s\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2\lib\net35\Newtonsoft.Json.dll D:\a\3\s\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2\lib\net40\Newtonsoft.Json.dll D:\a\3\s\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll D:\a\3\s\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2\lib\netstandard1.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll D:\a\3\s\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2\lib\netstandard1.3\Newtonsoft.Json.dll D:\a\3\s\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2\lib\portable-net40+sl5+win8+wpa81+wp8\Newtonsoft.Json.dll D:\a\3\s\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2\lib\portable-net45+win8+wpa81+wp8\Newtonsoft.Json.dll D:\a\3\s\packages\WindowsAzure.Storage.9.1.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll D:\a\3\s\packages\WindowsAzure.Storage.9.1.1\lib\netstandard1.0\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll D:\a\3\s\packages\WindowsAzure.Storage.9.1.1\lib\netstandard1.3\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll D:\a\3\s\packages\WindowsAzure.Storage.9.1.1\lib\win8\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll D:\a\3\s\packages\WindowsAzure.Storage.9.1.1\lib\wp8\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll D:\a\3\s\packages\WindowsAzure.Storage.9.1.1\lib\wpa\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll. Make sure that test discoverer & executors are registered and platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again.

I am using the following in the build definition:

Process

```
Agent queue: Hosted VS2017

Get Sources
Select a Source: TFVC
```

Phase 1

```
Agent Queue: Hosted VS2017

Demands
Exists: msbuild, visualstudio, vstest
```

NuGet Restore

```
Version: 2
Command: restore
Path to solution, packages.config or project.json:  **/*.sln

Use packages from NuGet.org
```

Build solution **.sln

```
Visual Studio Build 
Build solution **\*.sln
Version = 1.*
Solution = **\*.sln
Visual Studio Version = Latest
```

Test Runs (Visual Studio Test)

```
Version = 2.*
Select tests using = Test assemblies

Test Assemblies = **\*.dll
                  !**\*TestAdapter.dll
                  !**\obj\**
Search Folder = $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)

Test mix contains UI Tests

Select test platform using = Version

Update test attachments = Checked

Control Options = Enabled
```

Comment: What's the name of your test project? Is it a general Coded UI test project?

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of Build pipeline & Coded UI task to check the pipeline & configuration

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have found the issue. It was a second CodedUITest.cs file and was missing [CodedUITest] - that was the reason VSTS couldn't find any test method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comparing the code with another test I found the reason was because CodedUITest.cs file was missing [CodedUITest] after the namespace. I have added it and VSTS now can find the test method.